# create an object array from another object accessing the key

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
const allocatedItem= []
```

i have an an array of objects

```
const g={
    "Galley1": {
        "id": "Box-1",
        "rollNo": "",
        "name": "Flasks",
        "bgColorCode": "#058af7"
    },
    "Galley2": {
        "id": "Box-2",
        "rollNo": "",
        "name": "Perishable and Water Cart",
        "bgColorCode": "#f5f102"
    },
    "Galley3": {
        "id": "Box-3",
        "rollNo": "",
        "name": "Drystores and Cups",
        "bgColorCode": "#6e6e67"
    },
    "Galley4": {
        "id": "Box-5",
        "rollNo": "",
        "name": "Vaccum Flasks",
        "bgColorCode": "#c0c0c0"
    },
    "Galley11": {
        "id": "Box-2",
        "rollNo": "",
        "name": "Perishable and Water Cart",
        "bgColorCode": "#f5f102"
    },
    "Galley10": {
        "id": "Box-7",
        "rollNo": "",
        "name": "Flexi SMU",
        "bgColorCode": "#058af7"
    },
    "Galley9": {
        "id": "Box-6",
        "rollNo": "",
        "name": "ROB SMU",
        "bgColorCode": "#6e6e67"
    },
    "Galley8": {
        "id": "Box-8",
        "rollNo": "",
        "name": "Dessert Cart",
        "bgColorCode": "#c0c0c0"
    },
    "Galley7": {
        "id": "Box-9",
        "rollNo": "",
        "name": "Liquor",
        "bgColorCode": "#f5f102"
    },
    "Galley6": {
        "id": "Box-10",
        "rollNo": "",
        "name": "Meals Tray",
        "bgColorCode": "#009933"
    },
    "Galley5": {
        "id": "Box-11",
        "rollNo": "",
        "name": "Bottles",
        "bgColorCode": "#058af7"
    }
}
```

i need to make allocated items arrays in such a way that it should be having objects in the structure

```
    const allocatedItem= [ {
          "cartId": g.Galley1.name,
          "itemId": "1"
      },
      {
          "cartId": g.Galley2.name,
          "itemId": "2"
      },
{
          "cartId": g.Galley3.name,
          "itemId": "2"
      }
]
```

The objects should be added till the number of galley objects are mapped in cartId ie Galley4,5,6 ,9etc. The itemId should be auto incremented.Is there a way to do this rather than accessing it from the object like i did for cartId.

Comment: Post JavaScript as a [mcve].

Comment: It is not an array, it is an object (a dictionary consisting of unordered key-value pairs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate over the `g` object, and achieve desired result.

```js
const g = {
  Galley1: {
    id: "Box-1",
    rollNo: "",
    name: "Flasks",
    bgColorCode: "#058af7"
  },
  Galley2: {
    id: "Box-2",
    rollNo: "",
    name: "Perishable and Water Cart",
    bgColorCode: "#f5f102"
  },
  Galley3: {
    id: "Box-3",
    rollNo: "",
    name: "Drystores and Cups",
    bgColorCode: "#6e6e67"
  },
  Galley4: {
    id: "Box-5",
    rollNo: "",
    name: "Vaccum Flasks",
    bgColorCode: "#c0c0c0"
  },
  Galley11: {
    id: "Box-2",
    rollNo: "",
    name: "Perishable and Water Cart",
    bgColorCode: "#f5f102"
  },
  Galley10: {
    id: "Box-7",
    rollNo: "",
    name: "Flexi SMU",
    bgColorCode: "#058af7"
  },
  Galley9: {
    id: "Box-6",
    rollNo: "",
    name: "ROB SMU",
    bgColorCode: "#6e6e67"
  },
  Galley8: {
    id: "Box-8",
    rollNo: "",
    name: "Dessert Cart",
    bgColorCode: "#c0c0c0"
  },
  Galley7: {
    id: "Box-9",
    rollNo: "",
    name: "Liquor",
    bgColorCode: "#f5f102"
  },
  Galley6: {
    id: "Box-10",
    rollNo: "",
    name: "Meals Tray",
    bgColorCode: "#009933"
  },
  Galley5: {
    id: "Box-11",
    rollNo: "",
    name: "Bottles",
    bgColorCode: "#058af7"
  }
};


const allocatedItem = [];
let index = 1;

for (let key in g) {
  let obj = {};
  obj.cartId = g[key].name;
  obj.itemId = index + "";
  allocatedItem.push(obj)
  index += 1;
}

console.log(allocatedItem)
```

The for loop iterates over the keys of the `g` object. We also declared the `index` variable, with value of 1, to keep track of the `itemId`. Inside the for loop, we declare an empty object, and add the required key-values to it. Then, we append the object to the array.